# Difference between frontend and backend in an akka cluster?

Tags: scala, akka

Here is the code:

---

```
// Backend.scala
package com.packt.akka.cluster

import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorSystem, Props, RootActorPath}
import akka.cluster.ClusterEvent.MemberUp
import akka.cluster._
import com.packt.akka.commons._
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

class Backend extends Actor {

  val cluster = Cluster(context.system)

  // subscribe to cluster changes, MemberUp
  // re-subscribe when restart
  override def preStart(): Unit = {
    cluster.subscribe(self, classOf[MemberUp])
  }

  override def postStop(): Unit = {
    cluster.unsubscribe(self)
  }

  def receive = {
    case Add(num1, num2) =>
      println(s"I'm a backend with path: ${self} and I received add operation.")
      println(s"Result is ${num1 + num2}")
    case MemberUp(member) =>
      if(member.hasRole("frontend")){
        context.actorSelection(RootActorPath(member.address) / "user" / "frontend") ! BackendRegistration
      }
  }

}

object Backend {
  def initiate(port: Int = 8991): Unit = {
    val config = ConfigFactory.parseString(s"akka.remote.netty.tcp.port=$port").
      withFallback(ConfigFactory.load().getConfig("Backend"))

    val system = ActorSystem("ClusterSystem", config)

    val Backend = system.actorOf(Props[Backend], name = "Backend")
  }
}
```

---

```
// ClusterApp.scala
package com.packt.akka.cluster

import akka.cluster._
import com.packt.akka.commons._
import akka.actor.{ Actor, ActorRef, ActorSystem, Props }


object ClusterApp extends App {

  //initiate frontend node
  Frontend.initiate()

  //initiate three nodes from backend
  Backend.initiate(2552)

  Backend.initiate(2560)

  Backend.initiate(2561)

  Thread.sleep(10000)

  Frontend.getFrontend ! Add(2, 4)
  Frontend.getFrontend ! Add(2, 5)
  Frontend.getFrontend ! Add(2, 6)

}
```

---

```
// Frontend.scala
package com.packt.akka.cluster

import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorRef, ActorSystem, Props, Terminated}
import com.packt.akka.commons._
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

import scala.util.Random


class Frontend extends Actor {

  var backends = IndexedSeq.empty[ActorRef]

  def receive = {
    case Add if backends.isEmpty =>
      println("Service unavailable, cluster doesn't have backend node.")
    case addOp: Add =>
      println("Frontend: I'll forward add operation to backend node to handle it.")
      backends(Random.nextInt(backends.size)) ! addOp
    case BackendRegistration if !(backends.contains(sender())) =>
      backends = backends :+ sender()
      context watch (sender())
    case Terminated(a) =>
      backends = backends.filterNot(_ == a)

  }

}


object Frontend {

  private var _frontend: ActorRef = _

  def initiate() = {
    val config = ConfigFactory.load().getConfig("Frontend")
    val system = ActorSystem("ClusterSystem", config)
    _frontend = system.actorOf(Props[Frontend], name = "frontend")
  }

  def getFrontend = _frontend
}
```

---

```
// application.conf
Frontend {
  akka {
    actor {
      provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
    }
    remote {
      log-remote-lifecycle-events = off
      netty.tcp {
        hostname = "127.0.0.1"
        port = 2551
      }
    }

    cluster {
      roles = ["frontend"]
      seed-nodes = [
        "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2551"]

      auto-down-unreachable-after = 10s
    }
  }
}

Backend {
  akka{
    actor {
      provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
    }
    remote {
      log-remote-lifecycle-events = off
      netty.tcp {
        hostname = "127.0.0.1"
        port = 0
      }
    }

    cluster {
      roles = ["backend"]
      seed-nodes = [
        "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2551"]

      auto-down-unreachable-after = 10s
    }
  }
}
```

A few questions:

1. Why is the backend subscribed on the cluster, while the frontend not?
2. So, is frontend actually a member of the cluster?
3. Port number of backend is given once in application.conf, and once again in the initiate method, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Seems like in this example we want the backends (workers) to discover the frontend (master) and register themselves instead of allowing the frontend to listen to cluster events, so this is matter of design I guess.
2. Frontend is a member of the cluster, it's just not subscribed to
   cluster events.
3. Frontend is initialized with the settings from application.conf and it's also a seed node, while backends have port 0 in application.conf, what means that they will be initialized with random port unless you override it programmatically like in the initiate method.